# calling an item, using javascript in boostrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

```
 <ul>
 <li><a onClick="showsub('activ')" class="activ">activ</a></li>
 <li>.........</li>
 </ul>
```

(option1-selected) option2  option3 ... ...
option1  (option2-selected) option3 ........

The above, is been used by bootstrap, so when the user click on one of each li
it will be active and it will "selected and looks different than the others".
I have the above code, there is two ways to Make this work. 
First, it to add a class="Active" using javascript ... or to remove class="" nothing
which will return it to its original

The second way, is to add data-toggle="pill"

```
 <li><a onClick="showsub('activ')" data-toggle="pill">activ</a></li>
```

Thus, bootstrap whatsoever javascript will make this work automatically. if you just add
data-toggle="pill" then you don't have to add any javascript..

my problem is;
How can I call specific li? and have the data-toggle="pill" works?

for example..
say you have the following
menue

home   info   contact

(home)                           (info)                   (contact)
news   articles   others         about   bio             admin    feedback

my problem, is I want when I click info, to show bio
or when I click home, to show news without clicking news to show information.
I have done this, by using two functions.
first function to call home,info, contact..
then.

```
if onClick = home
   call function show(news):
elif onClick =info
   call function show(bio):
```

this works fine, but it will sometimes looks like this ...

news    (articles)     others

news contents ... bla bla bla

---

notice that, articles is selected, but news (contents) are shown instead.
I hope you get the point.. 
I want when I call show(news) to be able to use data-toggle="pill"

```
if onClick = home
   call function show(news):
   & also pill (news) if it is not pill
```

so the when I call home, news will appear and also it active on the menue

(home active)
(news active) article  other
news contents

Comment: So your point is that the menu is not in sync with the contents ur loading,you can try this. `$('ul li a').removeClass('active');$('ul li a').eq(<index of the menu which needs to be loaded>).addClass('active');`

Comment: So lets close this question, if you have found your answer, this would reduce the number of Open Questions from the pool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

**JS CODE:**

```
$('ul li a').removeClass('active');
$('ul li a').eq(<index of the menu which needs to be loaded>).addClass('active');
```

*Note: this may not be the final Solution, its just a prototype of what could become a final solution.*

Happy Coding :)